# Slick and bonecp: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already error

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, bonecp

Locally when I am developing my application I launch my play2 application using `sbt run`

I love how I can make code changes, and then reload my browser to see my changes.

After about roughly 10 code changes or so, I get a postgresql too many connection error (see below).

My db connection is using the below DatabaseAccess.scala class.

I'm guessing on each reload it is creating a bunch of connections to postgresql.  In my Global am currently doing:

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Global.onStart")

    DatabaseAccess.loadConfiguration()
  }
```

In production I am also worried that if I make multiple deploys in a short period of time, or start/stop my service I might run into this problem also.

**How can I ensure all connections are destroyed?  I know I can either put something in the onStart or OnStop but I'm not really sure how to clear the connections that might have existed previously.** *(assuming this isn't a bug)*

I did create a release() method that I was calling on onStop but that didn't seem to work:

```
 def release() {
    configs = Map[String, BoneCPConfig]()
    dataSources = Map[String, BoneCPDataSource]()
    databases = dataSources.map { case(key, value) => (key, Database.forDataSource(value)) }
  }
```

All I did was re-init the vars so I guess that wasn't really what I needed to do.

**My data access pattern is as follows:**

```
def getById(userId: Int): Option[User] = {
    db.withSession { implicit session =>
      return userDao.getById(userId)
    }
  }
```

My database access class looks like:

https://github.com/TechEmpower/FrameworkBenchmarks/blob/master/unfiltered/src/main/scala/DatabaseAccess.scala

My application.conf connection looks like:

```
#postgresql
db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
db.default.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testweb_development"
db.default.user = "testdbuser"
db.default.password = ""
db.default.minConnections = 4
db.default.maxConnections = 24
db.default.maxThreads = 2
```

Locally when developing after about approximately 10 code changes and sbt doing it's nice partial class reloads I get this error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[SQLException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost/testweb_development, username = testdbuser. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:291)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:120)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$4.createConnection(JdbcBackend.scala:47)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:302)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:302)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.close(JdbcBackend.scala:316)
    at scala.slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.withSession(DatabaseComponent.scala:31)
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$4.withSession(JdbcBackend.scala:46)
    at com.exampleapp.services.UserServiceImpl.getById(UserService.scala:37)
    at controllers.UsersController$$anonfun$show$1.apply(UsersController.scala:84)
    at controllers.UsersController$$anonfun$show$1.apply(UsersController.scala:76)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220)
    at controllers.ActionWithContext$.invokeBlock(BaseController.scala:42)
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:309)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:108)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:107)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:107)
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:100)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493)
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

**Environment**

```
I am running scala 2.10.3, play 2.2.3

I am launching my app using sbt run.

Postgresql driver version: 9.1-901.jdbc4
slick version: 2.0.1
bonecp version: 0.8.0.RELEASE
```

Comment: I found [this](https://gist.github.com/filipelenfers/7914993) gist, maybe it can help you.

Comment: @EndeNeu I updated my question with how I am using the db (I am using db.withSession {...}) already but thanks for that point as it makes things clearer.

Comment: I never user Bonecp but I guess that the slick `withSession` is handled correctly, the problem is the `datSource` connection opened by Bonecp, looking at the gist you need to call `dataSource.close()` even though the slick session has expired.

Comment: @EndeNeu thanks I did that I'll report back if that worked (it makes sense). So if not boncecp what do you use?

Comment: Slick has his own jdbc driver classes, for Postgres I use `scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._` for my models (e.g. CRUD operations) while to open a session (with `DB.withSession`) I use simply `play.api.db.slick._` and `play.api.Play.current`. I actually don't have a class that handles connections, in my entry point I simply use `DB.withSession` and pas the session around implicitly.

Comment: @EndeNeu I see, so you don't use a pool of connections then right?  I use the same Postgres driver as you, but I have a pool of connections.

Comment: Ah I see now, I went to read some documentation on Bonecp. My application currently doesn't need a connection pool, although it could be useful in the future, and by the way I didn't know Slick had no support for pooling.

Comment: @EndeNeu I'd like to give you credit, the .close made it work.  If you want you can write an answer with that info.

Comment: Good to know my guess was right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Slick` handles session closing automatically. From the documentation:

> The Database object’s withSession method creates a Session, passes it to a given function and closes it afterwards. If you use a connection pool, closing the Session returns the connection to the pool.

The problem is the `Bonecp`'s `dataSource` connections which are not closed, as showed on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/filipelenfers/7914993)  you need to close them manually using `dataSource.close()`.