# Play - HikariCP connections not released back to pool

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, hikaricp

In a Play project which has two sub-projects, we are trying HikariCP and it does not seem to release connections back to pool and throws this exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Timeout of 30000ms encountered waiting for connection.
```

Here's what debug shows after six simple queries:

```
[DEBUG] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - Before cleanup pool stats pool1 (total=5, inUse=5, avail=0, waiting=1)
[DEBUG] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - After cleanup pool stats pool1 (total=5, inUse=5, avail=0, waiting=1)
[DEBUG] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - Timeout failure pool stats pool1 (total=5, inUse=5, avail=0, waiting=0)
[ERROR] application - Error in datastore operation detected.
java.sql.SQLException: Timeout of 30000ms encountered waiting for connection.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:207) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:93) ~[HikariCP-java6-2.0.1.jar:na]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$3.createConnection(JdbcBackend.scala:47) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
[DEBUG] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - Before cleanup pool stats pool1 (total=5, inUse=4, avail=1, waiting=0)
[DEBUG] c.z.h.p.HikariPool - After cleanup pool stats pool1 (total=5, inUse=4, avail=1, waiting=0)
```

We are using **two** Postgres databases with two pools and versions are:

```
Play: 2.3.3
Scala: 2.11.1
HikariCP: 2.0.1
Play-hikaricp: 1.4.1
Postgres: 9.3
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Enabling leak detection (leakDetectionThreshold=10000) generates following warnings:

```
[WARN] c.z.h.p.LeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: null
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$3.createConnection(JdbcBackend.scala:47) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:152) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
[WARN] c.z.h.p.LeakTask - Connection leak detection triggered, stack trace follows
java.lang.Exception: null
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef$$anon$3.createConnection(JdbcBackend.scala:47) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn$lzycompute(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.conn(JdbcBackend.scala:397) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:152) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
    at scala.slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:389) ~[slick_2.11-2.1.0.jar:0.8.0]
```

Comment: This is likely a Slick configuration issue, possibly due to deferred query execution after obtaining a connection.  I would suggest enabling leak detection to see if there are threads hanging onto connections without returning them to the pool in a timely fashion (> 10 seconds).

Comment: @brettw: Thanks. I updated the question. What does this exactly mean? I noticed some other users with two databases/pools have had a similar issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the [bug report](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/104#issuecomment-60857459) on github, this appears to be [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065435/slick-and-bonecp-org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-sorry-too-many-clie).  I am not a Play/slick developer, so I do not know what the underlying issue is.  But I do know that it is not a bug in HikariCP.  Connections that are closed are returned to the pool immediately.

Asynchronous systems like Scala, if not properly used when accessing resources that can block, can develop a backlog of pending execution tasks that start to suffer from resource timeouts.  This is typically mediated by separate thread execution pools for blocking access.  I would expect that kind of thing to be wired into the Slick framework, but as I said above I am not really familiar with Slick.

Comment: closing the sessions manually solved the problem. I hope Slickians will include an easier way for this. Thanks for the great work.

Comment: @centr Just wondering if it's a sustainable solution. Did this work for you for a long run?